# how does the regex like ".*" work in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am puzzled by regular expression like `.*`

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "scott";
$text =~ s/.*/\//g;
print $text;
```

Output: `//`

So, I don't know why the result is `//` rather than `/`.

Comment: `.` matches any character and `*` matches 0 or any occurrence of the previous. So `.*` means match anything

Comment: @bansi So why doesn't it *match everything*?

Comment: `perl -MData::Dumper -e '$text="scott"; $text =~ s/(.*)/print Dumper $1/ge'`

Comment: We can see that the regex engine tries to match one more time when it reaches the end of string, but I think the question is why does it keep going when it has already reached the end of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time through, `.*` matches 5 characters starting at position zero (`scott`). This gets replaced with `/`.

`/g` means match as many times as possible, so it tries again, this time start at position five.

The second time through, `.*` matches 0 characters starting at position five (empty string). This gets replaced with `/`.

The third time through, `.*` goes to matches 0 characters starting at position five (""), but there's a check that makes sure it doesn't match the same starting position and length twice in a row. So it advances the position and tries to match at position six. Since that's outside the string it fails.

Comment: I agree with you. actually, if I remove /g option, it will be / (one slash). In addition, s/.*?t/g => // and s/.*?t/ => /, so I am sure of you.

Comment: it won't match for zero length at the same starting position twice in a row; with a non-zero length, it can't have the same starting position

Comment: @ysth, Same thing. My wording makes it a clear an infinite loop would ensue otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

`.*` matches two times.  First, it matches "scott".  Then it matches the empty string *after* "scott".

Comment: Indeed it does.  Run with `use re "debug";` to see who is correct :)

Comment: This one is. Use `$text =~ s/(.*)/-> $1 <-/g;` to easily verify.

Comment: hey guys we are not on a vote war site. it won't help others reaching in hope to find a solution.it would be nice to explain when downvoting. it will help the poster to understand their mistake. we are all learning here.

Comment: sorry. I am still puzzled.
if I use $text =~ s/^.*/\//g; you know, the result will be "/"(only one slash). I want to kown why it happend. so, if it matches the empty string after "scott", how to explain this.

Comment: Keep in mind that the regex continues to *look* at the original string while it builds the result in a new one.  `/^.*/` can't match again at the end of `"scott"`, because the `^` only allows it to match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I can believe this is what's happening, but it leaves a lot unanswered. Why does perl's regexp engine interpret the match this way, while others (vim and GNU sed for example) do it the other way (`s/.*/x/g` results in a single `x`)? If we were talking about POSIX regexps, which behavior would be correct according to the standard? Either GNU sed has a bug, or perl has a weird deviation (which we can't call a bug only because perl doesn't claim to follow any standards but its own)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I don't know that POSIX deals with this and I would be very surprised if it disallowed zero-length matches at the end of a string; the issue isn't what a regex matches, but where and how often it tries to match, something that is understandably tool-dependent